# Why is this code passing in the size in BITS to opengl's glBufferData method instead of bytes (java)

Tags: java, opengl

According to the opengl documentation when you call glBufferData the size parameter needs to be in bytes.

However this is a snippet from a program (that works perfectly fine)

```
long vertBsize = ((short)5) * 4l * 4l; 
glBindBuffer ( GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbuffer);
glBufferData ( GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertBsize , points, GL.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

According to the java documentation a short is 16-bits so in my mind this code snippet is incorrectly sending the number of BITS in the points buffer.

Am I stupid/way too tired or am I missing something

Comment: Can you show the definition/allocation of `points`? This might well be correct, but it's impossible to tell without seeing the actual size. For example, `points` could be 5 vertices with 4 components each, with each component 4 bytes (float). So 5 * 4 * 4 would be the correct size in bytes.

Answer (score 1):

@Reto Koradi's - question for more detail ultimately led me to the answer.

The points buffer contains all floats. The floats are split into sets of four:

```
{1.0,2.0,4.0,1.0,
 2.0,3.0,8.0,1.0,
 3.0,4.0,2.0,1.0,
 2.0,3.0,8.0,1.0,
 1.0,2.0,4.0,1.0}
```

Since a float == 32 bits == 4bytes. The formula 5(sets of floats)* 4(floats per set) * 4(bytes of data per float)  does indeed come out to the correct amount of bytes.